# How to solve Warning in log(z) : NaNs produced in R?

Tags: r, simulation, distribution

I try to run [K-S test simulation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132652/how-to-determine-which-distribution-fits-my-data-best) with different data and with GEV distribution but I get 50 warnings of `Warning in log(z): NaNs produced`

This is my data `t1 = 2.1466558  2.9447386  2.1410642  1.8847492  2.0233282  2.1907725  3.1755095  2.1142972  2.1889601  2.8422979  1.8555857  1.0429501  2.1383811  3.9976282 14.0612719  6.0016379  4.0426939  3.9845386  5.1821300  3.8703266  2.9009807  3.8450287  6.1019829  4.1811626  8.0737452  2.8416879  3.1656657  2.1342049  1.9984793  2.8037649  6.9629563  2.8223349 10.9695854  1.8985456  0.9444765  6.0065642  2.0394709  9.1677515  5.0589429  4.1036932  4.9599679  3.0425898  1.9477278  3.0447457  8.1563085  4.9423730  3.1336760  1.8389239  3.1262185  1.1628846  3.8445247  2.1454052  1.9209593  0.9197765  2.8171347  8.0249643 13.1267940  6.8506226  2.0811591  2.8517716  2.8864796  1.8227987  8.1442224  2.8798242  5.1112049  2.8529055  6.8265215  1.0436781  3.8380311  2.9659720  3.0153516  2.8497134  24.0545609  3.1952943  3.9564030  7.1348925  3.0067497  2.8581224  13.0294469  1.8576194  2.8081190  6.0940443  1.9729950  4.1334539  9.9874363  2.0489537  1.9479052  2.8050009  3.1097060  8.9115900  23.8376271  3.9219177  2.9991323  3.8501608  4.1910852  4.9508869  11.9260378  5.1473547  6.1864583  2.8165587  3.8589393  5.1742220  2.8812650  4.1469513  2.9816058  6.9291070  4.0086371  2.8950365  3.1368533  2.9716707  4.0936148  4.0987735  8.8792285  2.9914305  15.9832293 11.1705646  4.1691180  2.0268396  9.1313510  2.8457873  5.8162405  5.1019303  2.9493099  3.1892744  6.1027555  5.9852653  6.0070368  5.0606722  3.8827039  2.8579010  3.1809342  2.8639117  4.0446142  8.1086074  6.9708477  3.9406243  3.9113551  2.8471808  3.9408469  1.8318536  4.8696027  6.1638158 10.0075047  4.0620721  2.1995222  2.9713600  0.9827086 11.8048057  3.1639570  4.1820899  2.8913417  5.1807095  1.8735194  3.8650210  2.9308563  6.9203276  7.0470336  2.1721080  1.9304191  2.9782089  4.9717892  1.8260324  4.0094237  6.0354774  4.1934337  3.8605304  6.9868062  9.0001938  19.9510362 10.0213967  1.9980948  1.9564188 10.0595901  5.9441410  5.9212171  1.9805753  2.8141160  9.8859371  2.1912938  5.0260191  7.0394183  3.1071499  4.8651357  4.8464983  3.1653826  4.0813080  0.9293124  2.0533324  3.1302422  5.0649879  1.9045972  3.0304574  6.1638933  1.8765108  2.1042605  5.0677281  7.9328270  5.0485400  11.8101217  2.8496955  3.9641349  2.0423748  3.9535697 10.1833001  1.9963743  3.9404075  1.0794579  5.1952880  2.1310139  3.1615550  4.1934939  2.1528778  1.8080386  7.8411243  9.8299614  6.0534968  4.0174467  2.0321006  6.8884815  3.1990381  3.9448174  4.1087308  2.8989261  3.1667614  3.0734750  4.9591400  4.0537864  5.1886589  2.0860818  3.9166460  3.8028030  2.8333645  2.0257119  3.9347423  2.1057551  2.9608942  5.8546608  3.1449161  1.8630542  5.0733393  1.8331204  3.1629142  4.0929211  6.9565034  3.8253997  2.8041233  5.1246350  3.8994802  2.0389505  5.0663955  3.8854816  1.8575128  1.9655496  3.0056002  4.9812668  4.8201262`

I fit the GEV to the data:

`fit5 = fevd(t1, type="GEV")` using the function `fevd` in `extRemes` package. I wanna do K-S test simulation but get 50 warnings at this part:

```
stats <- replicate(n.sims, {
  r <- rgevd(n = length(t1),location=fit5$results$par["location"],
             shape= fit5$results$par["shape"], 
             scale = fit5$results$par["scale"])

  estfit.gev <- fevd(r, type = "GEV") # added to account for the estimated parameters

  as.numeric(ks.test(r, "pgevd",location=estfit.gev$results$par["location"],
                     shape= estfit.gev$results$par["shape"], 
                     scale = estfit.gev$results$par["scale"])$statistic)
```

how do I solve this `Warning in log(z): NaNs produced`? I tried to use absolute `r` value but I still get the same warnings

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Your question is not a MWE because you don't include your input data, complete code, nor packages used *in this post*.

Comment: Hi, I've edited this post. @Limey